# PowerShell/PowerCLI reference to previous object

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am working on simple reporting one-liner and I can't get it to work.

I am retrieving the ESXi hosts by cmdlet `Get-VMHost`. `Get-VMHost` is piped into `Get-VMHostSysLogServer`.

As the output I get the `Host` and `Port` properties. I would like to display the following properties:

- Name (from `Get-VMHost`)
- Host and Port (both from `Get-VMHostSysLogServer`).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean the `Get-VMHostSysLogServer` cmdlet?

Comment: Yes exactly. But in reality the question is how do I display name "before pipe" and display the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution, that builds a custom object with the properties that you want:

```
Get-VMHost | ForEach-Object {

    $SysLog = $_ | Get-VMHostSysLogServer

    ForEach ($SysLogServer in $SysLog) {
        $Result = @{
            VMHost = $_.name
            SysLogHost = $SysLogServer.Host
            Port = $SysLogServer.Port
        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Result
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Uses a ForEach-Object loop to iterate through each VM Host returned by `Get-VMHost` (represented as the current pipeline item via `$_`).
- Gets the SysLogServers of each Host in to `$SysLog`
- Loops through all SysLogServers, building a hashtable `@{ }` of the desired properties.
- Uses `New-Object` to output an object using the properties in the Hashtable which is returned to the Pipeline.

If you'd like to capture the results to a variable, just add `$YouVar =` before `Get-VMHost`.

If you want to send on the results to another cmdlet that accepts pipeline input (such as Export-CSV) you can do that directly as the end, just append `| Export-CSV Your.csv` after the last closing `}`. This is the benefit of using `ForEach-Object` as the outer loop, it supports the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you very much for help Mark. I especially appreciate an explanation how all works together. This will make my life easier for future "fun" with PowerCLI ;)